# Disable the toolbar from aquamacs in my init file

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I want to permanently disable the GUI toolbar (the little buttons for "New" "Open", etc.) from aquamacs in my .emacs file.  I have seen suggestions that you disable it in the gui and the go to Options >> Appearance >> Adopt Face and Frame as Default and then set that to permanent, but that is not working for me.  I was hoping for something I could add to my .emacs that will disable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting the following in your ~/.emacs file:

```
(tool-bar-mode 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using Mavericks and creating ~/.emacs and put (tool-bar-mode 0) did not work. Instead, I just added the line in the ~/Library/Preference/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el file, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

building on thomas' answer add

```
(set-tool-mode 0)
```

to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, creating the file as needed